# Creating a Concentration memory-style game with CSS/HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, game

I am doing a pre-cohort coursework for General Assembly and I am somewhat stuck. I have tried making several changes, but it never seems to work right. I am trying to use Career Karma to get assistance, but if you've ever worked with them, it is all dependent on how many people are online and who actually knows what they are doing.

Here's the instructions:

[image: Instructions pg. 7/10]

[image: Instructions pg. 8/10]

And here's what I have finished with so far. I have tried many different coding changes and none of them seem to work.

[image: Updated to what I have so far.]

The if...else statements seem to be the worst.

```
const cards = ['queen', 'queen', 'king', 'king'];
console.log(cards.slice([0, 3]));
let cardOne = [[0]];
let cardTwo = [[1]];
let cardThree = [[2]];
let cardFour = [[3]];

cardsInPlay = [];
cardsInPlay.push(cards[0]);
console.log("User flipped " + cards[0]);
cardsInPlay.push(cards[1]);
console.log("User flipped " + cards[1]);

if(cardOne == cardTwo)
{
alert("You found a match!")
};
if (cardOne !== cardTwo)
{
alert("Sorry, try again.")
};
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) combined with [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) might come handy here

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to look at it right now!

Comment: I was able to use the information you gave me, Sunil, as well as do a little troubleshooting with a little help from the console in the web browser when I brought up the index in the browser. Thank you!! That made it once again read "User flipped" + card name. Now, the issue is that part above in the picture that asks you to write an if/if...else combination statement that will find out if the length of the array is equal to 2. I have been researching an am unable to find that one anywhere on the internet.

Comment: That and when I open the index in a browser it does an automatic pop up instead of the click action and says "Sorry, try again.", probably since it hasn't made me set up the click button action.

Comment: Please don't remove the original code after getting suggestions from others. It will create confusion to other contributors here and might change the problem comlpetely. Instead, you can add your attempts or modifications along with original code posted. Moreover, please visit [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as after the edit, it seems that the problem it not suited for codereview but for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Sunil That's only valid if answers arrive. Until answers arrive, OP is free to change the code. Comments are irrelevant in that regard.

Comment: My apologies. I was unsure, as it said to make sure to edit your code so people can see updates. I will make sure to leave the original code. Thank you for your help!